# Is the return value of the link function of a directive used?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Is the return value of the `link` function of a directive used?

I am using AngularJS 1.4.

This question stems from seeing an object being new'd up and then returned from a `link` function.

For example, from a directive definition:

```
// ...
link: function(scope, $element, attrs, ngModelController) {
  return new Link(scope, $element, $window, ngModelController);
},
// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that it is not used.

To check it, i set up [this simple plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4k6Qx3Qq8bCFREh4jB5r?p=preview), wrote a dummy directive that only has `debugger;` to set up a breakpoint e.g.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope){
      debugger;
    }
  }
});
```

While running it, i opened the debugging tools using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key and when looked up in the Call Stack, saw that no one consumes the returned value of the link function call

[image]